# Can a person be of more than one caste?

Tags: caste-system

For example people like da vinci who are talented in many fields can they belong to more than one cast? what if a person is very intellectual like a brahmin can fight like a kshatriya?What caste will he belong to?

Comment: One in a Varna can exhibit the gunas of another Varna; this doesn't change the varna. Vidura born shudra but intellect and still considered shudra but respected by Brahmanas. Sanjaya born suta, remained suta but respected by all like the knowledgeable Brahmana.

Comment: many of Atri's recent descendents have Multi-caste roots

Comment: @Kanthri What about Vishwamitra?

Comment: Vishwamitra's birth itself was destined to become a Brahmana and he went through a lot to teach there. And, he is probably the only such instance and reasons are well documented.

Answer (score 0):

The person will be a Kshatriya if he is interested in participating in war. If he just likes to learn how to use weapons, collects them out of interest, has a desire to teach princes the *Dhanurveda*, and has no interest in hurting anyone, then he is a brahmin. Examples will be Dronacharya. My justification is the Bhagavad Gita.

Bhagavad Gita, chapter 18, [verse 43](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/43):

> > शौर्यं तेजो धृतिर्दाक्ष्यं युद्धे चाप्यपलायनम् |
> > दानमीश्वरभावश्च क्षात्रं कर्म स्वभावजम् || 43||

> > śhauryaṁ tejo dhṛitir dākṣhyaṁ yuddhe chāpy apalāyanam
> > dānam īśhvara-bhāvaśh cha kṣhātraṁ karma svabhāva-jam

> > Valor, strength, fortitude, skill in weaponry, resolve never to retreat from battle, large-heartedness in charity, and leadership abilities, these are the natural qualities of work for Kshatriyas.

As per [verse 42](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/42) in chapter 18 of Bhagavat Gita,

> > शमो दमस्तप: शौचं क्षान्तिरार्जवमेव च |
> > ज्ञानं विज्ञानमास्तिक्यं ब्रह्मकर्म स्वभावजम् || 42||

> > śhamo damas tapaḥ śhauchaṁ kṣhāntir ārjavam eva cha
> > jñānaṁ vijñānam āstikyaṁ brahma-karma svabhāva-jam

> > Tranquility, restraint, austerity, purity, patience, integrity, knowledge, wisdom, and belief in a hereafter—these are the intrinsic qualities of work for Brahmins.

intellectuality is not a characteristic that distinguishes a Brahmin from the other castes. Kshatriyas (ex: military generals) can be intellectuals too.

Comment: Those are gunas. Suddenly the Varna doesn't change. Drona or Parashurama or Kripa didn't become Kshatriya because they took weapons. They were still Brahmanas.

Answer (score 0):

Caste is not equal to VARNA. Hinduism is of highest spirituality Sanaatana Dharmaa.

Sanatana Dharma advocates that person of a VARNA is better / best in his/ her VARNAASHRAMA. It means a person is a specialist in VARNA.

Modes of Survival in Kali Yuga against demonaic traits forces persons to do multiple jobs / acquire more intellectual abilities than required for life. This does not account for VARNAASHRAMA goal of PRAANA, TATVA and MOKSHA as described by Aacharyaas & Holy saints.

Summary: Intercaste abilities are just additional qualifications that pushed persons from their VARNAASHRA DHARMAA. In Kaliyuga a person instead of concentrating on SWADHARMA PARIPAALANAM has to do extra work/ knowledge acquisition to survive in the world with assets/ wealth.

People helping those in poverty (poor but good & sacred) are not constant in their good KARMA. They may have sins in kaliyuga such that they may neglect poor totally. Hence,

'WAYS TO SURVIVE ON EARTH AMIDST HEAVY CHALLENGES(INDUCED BY HUMAN & BEINGS)  CANT BE EQUATED TO VARNAASHRAMA DHARMAA.

VARNAASHRAMA DHARMA IS FOR MOKSHA. For oneness of people before God there is a way of life in Hinduism called SANAATANA DHARMA. Following SANAATANA DHARMA indicates that an expert in it is not just Brahmn/Kshtr/Vaish/Shudr but he/she by THYSELF IS INHERITING GOD.
He/She is very powerful on Earth through renounciation after making up one's own mind.

Ways of such conversion(Duality towards Godliness by : 1. NAISHKARMYAM 2. SANNYAASANAM

If you want to convert from your caste group to another caste for benefit & status(well & good), BUT you have to still undergo the good & evils which other caste faces. Hence it is advisable to be a good
" SANAATANI". This is called VEDAANTA SAARAM that may lead oneself to LIBERATION.

The powerful world of VEDAS & boons by just chants are in their last stages. Because, there is a hierarchy defined by GOD(not by humans) to enable "MODE OF ACCEPTANCE":

ACCEPTING A HUMAN BY ANOTHER HUMAN IS NOT AT ALL DIFFICULT BUT
What, why and by whom GOD accepts offerings from humans is clearly defined not just in one religion but entirely on Earth. To appreciate GOD is important for life.

Now in KaliYuga, only with VEDAANTASAARAM one has to live life on Earth without getting degraded in one's own values.

Comment: You really should be adding scriptural references to back up your answers.